# Apache production and dev servers behaving differently when addressed using FQDN

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

Our production Apache server works perfectly as either "https://prod.domain.com" or "https://prod" (this is internal, so DNS search path applies).   However, our Dev server works as "https://dev", but not as "https://dev.domain.com".  On Dev when you use the FQDN, you simply get the Index page.

They are using the same version of Apache (2.2.15) and the same version of OpenSSL (1.0.1e-57).  They are both CentOS 6, with similar but not identical packages and patches.

The config files are almost identical, the only difference (other than the names), is that the production server has a valid cert and the dev machine has a self-signed cert, neither expired.

The relevant portion of the Apache config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName dev.domain.com
        ServerAlias dev
```

The biggest clue is that on the production server, going to a bogus link using the FQDN and the short name, both failures are logged in "access_log".   On the dev machine, going to a bogus link using the short name is logged in "access_log", but going to a bogus link using the FQDN is logged in "ssl_access.log".

The DNS and local host file entries are the same and the machines can be pinged as either the short name or the FQDN locally and from the client.

Any ideas where to look?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: Is there some redirect happening perhaps ? I would try `curl  -L https://dev.domain.com` with and without FQDN, also try without https and compare results.

Comment: Add the output of `apache2ctl -S`. Maybe a well hidden `<VirutalHost>`?

Comment: To Anonymous: The only redirect is from :80 to :443.   I tried curl and got the same results as with a browser.   Normal web app with the short name, Index page with FQDN.

Comment: To Piotr:   The output of "apachectl -S" was interesting in that it showed one other difference between these machines.  The production machine the "default server" is different than the VirtualHostName.   On dev, the names are the same.   I've scheduled time tonight to play with that difference and see if it affects anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Piotr P. Karwasz who asked a question in the comments that got me pointed in a different direction.

The problem was that there was already a VirtualHost directive in another config file.  However, it wasn't immediately obvious, because the directive was in the form:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

Our production server had a different system host name than the VirtualHost name, so we didn't see the issue.   I used a different DNS name for the dev box and changed this VirtualHost line to use that name and the problem went away.

Brad